# Dynamically position vertical StripLine in SSRS 2008

Tags: charts, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I am building a Control Chart where the user selects an interrupt date and I would like to place the StripLine immediately *before* that. So, let's say a user selects July 2009 as their interrupt date, I'd like to place the StripLine at June 2009. Based on how I got the image below it looks like I need to use index-based placement. How can I determine where on the chart June 2009 is? The user can also select the start and end dates so it would vary chart to chart.

If it matters the horizontal axis labels are MYYYY but the values are YYYYMM for sorting. In the image below I set the IntervalOffset to 3, not 72009 or 200907.

I have the following chart with (what is right now) a statically positioned vertical strip line.

[image: Control Chart]

SSRS is not my strength so please let me know if you need additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK this is pretty specific to my scenario but I figured I'd post the answer in case it can help someone else. Setting the expression for IntervalOffset to the following value worked:

```
=IIf(
     Parameters!StartYear.Value = Parameters!InterruptYear.Value,
     CInt(Parameters!InterruptMonth.Value - Parameters!StartMonth.Value),
     CInt(
          (CInt(Parameters!InterruptYear.Value)*12+CInt(Parameters!InterruptMonth.Value)) -
          (CInt(Parameters!StartYear.Value)*12+CInt(Parameters!StartMonth.Value))
         )
    )
```